# How do you interpret ARIMA coefficients?

Tags: r, arima, interpretation

I have this ARIMA model:

```r
> arima(train,c(0,2,1))

Call:
arima(x = train, order = c(0, 2, 1))

Coefficients:
          ma1
      -0.8873
s.e.   0.0505

sigma^2 estimated as 22210:  log likelihood = -810.08,  aic = 1624.17
```

and I wrote this mathematical model for it
$$
(1-B)^2 y_t=(1-\theta_1 B)\varepsilon_t.
$$
I am not sure about it or about the meaning of the coefficients in the output. Do they represent the values in the mathematical model?

<sub>Please excuse me my English is not good.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the formula right.

The R output tells you that $\theta_1=-0.8873$.